# Incorrect answer in integral of volume.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solid-of-revolution

Problem: Let $S$ the solid limited by the surfaces

\begin{align}
x= \sqrt{y^2 + z^2 }, \quad x=\sqrt{\frac{y^2 + z^2}{3}}, \quad x=\sqrt{a}
\end{align}

the value of parameter $a$ for the following equality to be met

\begin{align}
\int \int \int_S z dV = \pi 
\end{align}

is $\sqrt{2}$

My answer:

By the solid symetry, the centroid is at $z=0$ (thinking that the solid has homogeneus density $\rho=1$) so never $\int \int \int_S z dV = \pi $. What am I seeing wrong?.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to polar

$x = x\\
y = r\cos \theta\\
z = r\sin \theta$

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt a}\int_{x}^{x\sqrt 3} r^2\sin\theta\ dr\ dx\ d\theta$

I agree that will evaluate to 0.